# concatenate arrays to the numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

I am trying to add array to the beginning and end of an array in numpy and defined the following function:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft as fft
def E(X,N,M): 
    X=np.arange(-X,X)
    M=np.arange(0,M)
    E1=np.exp(-X**2)
    E1.shape=(np.size(E1),1)
    a=np.zeros((N,1))
    E1 = np.concatenate((a,E1,a))
    E2 = np.zeros((len(E1),len(M)))
    E2[:,0]=E1
    return E2
```

when I run the function, it gives me the following error:

```
print E(10,5,20)

    E2[:,0]=E1

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (30,1) into shape (30)
```

I am not sure what silly mistake I am making but i appreciate your help.

Thanks

If I now modified my original code as below:

```
def E(X,N,M): 
    X=np.arange(-X,X)
    M=np.arange(0,M)
    E1=np.exp(-X**2)
    N=np.zeros((N,))
    dX=X[1]-X[0]
    K=np.sqrt(1-(X/(len(X)*dX)))
    E1 = np.concatenate((N,E1,N))
    E2 = np.zeros((len(E1),len(M)))
    E2[:,0]=E1
    for k in M:
        E2[:,k+1] = fft.ifftshift(fft.fft(fft.fftshift(E2[:,k])))*np.exp(-1j*K)
        E2[:,k+1] = fft.fftshift(fft.ifft(fft.ifftshift(E2[:,k+1])))

    return E2
```

I will get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,) (20,)
```

could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The shapes in the error message make sense. `E2[:,0]` is a 1d slot.  You made `E1` 2d.  Either ravel it, or just don't add that 2nd dimension prior to concatenate.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the comment; actually I don't want to make E1 2d;
I only want to add vectors to the begging and end of the array; in Matlab it is done like this:
E1= vertcat(zeros(N,1),E1,zeros(N,1));
I wanted to the same in bumpy and that is how i did it.  Can you let me know how I should do it?

Comment: Try : `E2[:,0]=E1.ravel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make E1 a 2d array; concatenate will work with 1d:

```
def E(X,N,M): 
    X=np.arange(-X,X)
    M=np.arange(0,M)
    E1=np.exp(-X**2)
    #E1.shape=(np.size(E1),1)
    a=np.zeros((N,))
    E1 = np.concatenate((a,E1,a))
    E2 = np.zeros((len(E1),len(M)))
    E2[:,0]=E1
    return E2

In [401]: E(3,2,2)
Out[401]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.23409804e-04,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.83156389e-02,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.67879441e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  3.67879441e-01,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  1.83156389e-02,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it fixed the problem; however I modified my original code (as described in the original question above) and now i get different error.  Could you please let me know what I am missing? @hpaulj